# How to style extjs combobox height apart from css ways

Tags: javascript, extjs

The extjs Ext.form.ComboBox item setting height is not working using the

```
maxHeight: 100
minHeight: 100
maxBoxHeight: 100
minBoxHeight: 100
```

Even the setting of height of the div of the list is not working.
By default the height of the contained div is set to 0px. Any idea how to manipulate the height.

The html structure would be of the form as its a list of divs within a div.

Answer (score 0):

The setting you are searching for is [`listConfig`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.0/classic/Ext.form.field.ComboBox.html#cfg-listConfig). Here you can set configuration properties that will be passed to the Ext.view.BoundList's constructor.

```
Ext.create('Ext.form.ComboBox', {
   //[...]
    listConfig: {
        minWidth: 300,
        maxHeight: 40
    }
});
```

Here is a full example:
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/21bc

Comment: Im using the extjs 3 version :(

Comment: @ShyamSundarR Should it looks like this or did i misunderstood the question: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/21bg

Comment: ya, it looks like this, but the config of height, maxheight, minheight and all did not work

Comment: any idea on this?

Comment: What do you mean? The comment above includes a fiddle using v3 that limits the height of the dropdown. Saying it "doesn't work" provides no extra information, because it clearly does "work" as evidenced in the runnable fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

I done this before and it worked for me.

You can give cls config to your comboBox.

```
cls: 'textTransparent'
```

and you can give height in cls.

```
.textTransparent {
    height: 25px !important; // this will give the height
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
    margin: 0 !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks I fixed this issue before. There was some custom change to the way the extjs worked which introduced this issue. This was fixed.